# Webmin reporting incorrect local disk usage?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, webmin

So I just got a Dell T30, installed Ubuntu 16 on it. The boot drive is a 240gb SSD. I also have a 4 8TB WD Red RAID array (using RAID10).

On the dashboard of my Webmin I'm getting:

`Local disk space 14.65 TB total / 13.87 TB free / 799.29 GB used`

I have literally just set this up and moved only a handful of files to the raid mount. There is no way that there is 799.29 GB being used.

When I run `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            785M   27M  759M   4% /run
/dev/mapper/skillmatic--vg-root  212G   16G  186G   8% /
tmpfs                            3.9G  6.6M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sde1                        472M  113M  335M  26% /boot
tmpfs                            785M   92K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/md0                          15T   28G   14T   1% /mnt/raid
```

When I run `du -h --max-depth=1` at `/` I get:

```
667M    ./lib
 28G    ./mnt
4.0K    ./srv
9.5G    ./home
444K    ./dev
 17M    ./etc
 16M    ./bin
 27M    ./run
4.0K    ./lib64
 18M    ./sbin
 12K    ./media
 72K    ./root
3.9G    ./usr
4.0K    ./snap
178M    ./opt
3.4M    ./tmp
111M    ./boot
 16K    ./lost+found
   0    ./sys
   0    ./proc
1.6G    ./var
 44G    .
```

Any idea why the Webmin figure is way off?